# Speeding up the Processing power with a physical human brain possible?

Tags: hard-science, simulated-worlds, cybernetics

I heard possibilities of enhancing the framerate of the human mind to "see" slower. With Cybernetic augmentation, would it be possible to do this with-IN a simulated world? If so, how faster?

Also I need to mention.

-I don't mean conscious or brain uploading. From our current understanding of physics it's impossible. I simply mean just augmenting the brain to go in a faster processing rate JUST like the fast processing of the simulation.

-I do believe copying the mind to an A.I and using it as the subject for the example is obviously possible. But instead of the A.I I'm referring to just going to use the original Biological Conscious of the brain as mentioned before.

Comment: can you try to explain what you are asking? throwing some jargon is not the best way to get answers

Comment: Wasp, within the constraints you give, it should certainly be possible, if the OS allows you to increase your resource usage.  You might consider what are the psychological effects on people who abuse this idea...  You could have teenagers with the jaded minds of **centuries** of sim experience.  Note:  Q is at risk of being held; recommend edit question to focus on *effects* of this more than "is it possible".

Comment: Seems just as likely that your Smart Personal Assistant won't let you forget in the first place.

Comment: So you are suggesting to connect human brain to a Matrix-type simulation, only this simulation will run 10x faster, and somehow the brain would keep up?

Comment: @Alexander yes, but exactly how fast?

Comment: That's a good question. It's always been speculated (like [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/)) that our mind can run faster when not limited by our senses, but right now there's not much science available.

Comment: Maybe for that you would have to connect your brain with some empty huge artificial brain with a greater number of nerve cells... I say empty because I've heard about the possibility of old people being slower thinking and forgetting things because they have way more content in their brains... I'm not stating that... just pointing a possility (since I never looked for the scientific paper)

Comment: The brain can't be just sped up. (past some small amount from biological tweaks) You need to replace each neuron with faster components, basically mind uploading. How fast depends on computing power. If you have black hole computing (1kg black hole) then 10^32*faster. This gives 10^28 subjective years of procrastination. However 10^18 kg of matter must be fed into the black holes. (a sea) And the power radiated will be a million suns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly doubt the human mind can be enhanced by this crazy amount and here is why:

Think about the biochemistry of the brain. It takes time and energy for neurons to fire. Adrenaline can force your body to make it work quicker, but not indefinitely. How are the chemical reactions supposed to work millions of times quicker?

Electrical signals have a speed of 128 m/s within your body, if i remember correctly. So to speed up 1 second to make (relatively) 1 million seconds (or 1 microsecond to a second) would mean an electrical signal could just travel 128 micrometers within the body. That's not even from one half of the brain to the other.

Comment: Okay, i made a mistake. The factor would be 43200 to make a minute a month (not a million). But still a signal wouldn't get very far in a short timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes it's possible. Longer answer, there's more implications.

If the mental transfer process involves copying a mind into the simulation, then that's immortality and cloning right there. Whats to stop the user uploading multiples copies of their persona ?

If the transfer involves *moving* the mind from the biological body into the simulation, then that's immortality again, the singularity in fact. The biological body could die but the mind can live in the simulation. Whats to stop the mind being transferred back to a different body ? A younger one ? Maybe a younger clone of the user ?

The ramifications go way beyond getting a late homework assignment in on time :)

Comment: The idea of uploading brain / memory to a device is not new at all... A friend of mine wrote her phd thesis on old novels (books... literature) described human-machine hybrids and uploading memory was already a concept way back in the past...Nice, right?

Answer (score 0):

Note that the brain is a very interesting and complex system... It takes a lot of processing power to simulate brain ativity... 
[Scientists had already simulated brain activity](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/163051-simulating-1-second-of-human-brain-activity-takes-82944-processors) in machines and well... take a look in this paragraph:

> Scientists believe we all carry 80-100 billion nerve cells, or about
>   as many stars as there are in the Milky Way.
>   Knowing this, it shouldn’t come as a surprise that the researchers
>   were not able to simulate the brain’s activity in real time. It took
>   40 minutes with the combined muscle of 82,944 processors in K computer
>   to get just 1 second of biological brain processing time. While
>   running, the simulation ate up about 1PB of system memory as each
>   synapse was modeled individually.

So, If it will be possible in the future to upload your brain into a artificial workspace, it will require a bunch of technology, way more than we have so the simulated thinking process don't present lags.

That being said, I believe that if those tasks your simulated brain has to do are all computational and depend only on coding and programing (not in physical human actions), it would be possible to execute tasks that would take a lot of time in 5 minutes. But you have to consider how larger the processing power will be improved in this future time, in relation to this one we have